# Tensorflow error while making train_step.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been around this problem for the whole day and I can't find a solution online for what it could be.

I'm coding a convolutional neural network for classifying some BW images. I'm first reading the data, preparing the architecture of the network and then running the training part, but all the time I get this error while trying to train:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got -1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
     [[Node: Slice_1 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Shape_2, Slice_1/begin, Slice_1/size)]]
```

I can't find anything on the web that helps, me. And I can't figure out what is wrong. Thank you very much guys, I link you the whole code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import random

"""
N_CLASSES, number of classes of the dataset, 2 classes, one for an error and the other one if it is ok
BATH SIZE, is going to depend on the number of samples taht we have
IMAGE_HEIGHT, height of the images
IMAGE_WIDTH, width of the images
TOTAL_SIZE, total size of the image

"""
N_CLASSES = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 5
NUM_CHANNELS  = 1
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 696
IMAGE_WIDTH = 1024
TOTAL_SIZE = 1024*696

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

# Keep rate will do 0.6
keep_rate = 0.6
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

""" Function for encoding the label from string to int"""
def encode_label(label):
    return int(label)

""" Function for reading a label file separeted by ,
    F.E: /home/pacocp/dataset/image1.jpg,1
"""
def read_label_file(file):
    f = open(file)
    filepaths = []
    labels = []
    for line in f:
        filepath, label = line.split(",")
        filepaths.append(filepath)
        labels.append(encode_label(label))
    return filepaths, labels

"""This function is going to load the SEM images """
def load_images(dataset_path,test_labels_file,train_labels_file):
    # reading labels and file path
    train_filepaths, train_labels = read_label_file(dataset_path + train_labels_file)
    test_filepaths, test_labels = read_label_file(dataset_path + test_labels_file)
    """
    # transform relative path into full path
    train_filepaths = [ dataset_path + fp for fp in train_filepaths]
    test_filepaths = [ dataset_path + fp for fp in test_filepaths]
    """

    # for this example we will create or own test partition
    all_filepaths = train_filepaths + test_filepaths
    all_labels = train_labels + test_labels

    # convert string into tensors
    all_images = ops.convert_to_tensor(all_filepaths, dtype=dtypes.string)
    all_labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(all_labels, dtype=dtypes.int32)

    #now, we are going to create a partition vector
    test_set_size = 5
    partitions = [0] * len(all_filepaths)
    partitions[:test_set_size] = [1] * test_set_size
    random.shuffle(partitions)

    # partition our data into a test and train set according to our partition vector
    train_images, test_images = tf.dynamic_partition(all_images, partitions, 2)
    train_labels, test_labels = tf.dynamic_partition(all_labels, partitions, 2)

    # create input queues
    train_input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
                                    [train_images, train_labels],
                                    shuffle=False)
    test_input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
                                    [test_images, test_labels],
                                    shuffle=False)

    # process path and string tensor into an image and a label
    file_content = tf.read_file(train_input_queue[0])
    train_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content, channels=NUM_CHANNELS) #You have to change this line depending on the image format
    train_label = train_input_queue[1]

    file_content = tf.read_file(test_input_queue[0])
    test_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content, channels=NUM_CHANNELS)
    test_label = test_input_queue[1]


    # define tensor shape
    train_image.set_shape([IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH,1])
    test_image.set_shape([IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH,1])

    """ TEST FOR NOT USING BATCHES AND USING ALL THE IMAGES DIRECTLY
    print("Here")
    # collect batches of images before processing
    train_image_batch, train_label_batch = tf.train.batch(
                                    [train_image, train_label],
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
                                    #,num_threads=1
                                    )
    test_image_batch, test_label_batch = tf.train.batch(
                                    [test_image, test_label],
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
                                    #,num_threads=1
                                    )


    return {'train_image_batch':train_image_batch, 'train_label_batch':train_label_batch,
            'test_image_batch':test_image_batch, 'test_label_batch':test_label_batch}

    """

    return {'train_image_batch':train_image, 'train_label_batch':train_label,
            'test_image_batch':test_image, 'test_label_batch':test_label}

""" This is going to be used for creating the weights and the biases"""
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(data, weights):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(data, weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME') # We are not going to get the depth

def maxpool2d(data):
    """Here we are going to move two by two at a time size of the window movement of the window"""
    return tf.nn.max_pool(data, ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')

def convolutional_neural_network(data):

    """Here we are going to create the weights and biases variables for generating our neural network"""

    print("Creating first layer")
    w_conv1 = weight_variable([15, 15, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])


    x_image = tf.reshape(data, shape=[-1, 696, 1024, 1]) #Reshape the image, second and third elements
                                                         # are height and width, an the third dimension the colors channel


    #First convolutional layer
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,w_conv1 + b_conv1))
    h_pool1 = maxpool2d(h_conv1)

    print("Creating second layer")
    w_conv2 = weight_variable([15, 15, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    #Second convolutional layer
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1,w_conv2 + b_conv2))
    h_pool2 = maxpool2d(h_conv2)

    print("Craeating fully-conected layer")
    w_fc1 = weight_variable([1024, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    #Final
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2,[-1,1024])

    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1 )+ b_fc1)


    """The idea of dropout is for help us in a
    bigger neural network, dropout is going to help fight
    local minimuns"""

    fc_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate) #Compute dropout

    print("Creating output layer")
    w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, N_CLASSES])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([N_CLASSES])

    #Final layer with a softmax
    y = tf.matmul(fc_dropout, w_fc2)+ b_fc2

    print("CNN created")

    return y


'''Here is the main where we are going to train the convolutional neural network'''

#Here we read the images

dataset_path = "/media/datos/Dropbox/4ºaño/Image Analysis and Computer Vision/NanoFibers/DataSet/"
test_labels_file = "SEM_test_labels.txt"
train_labels_file = "SEM_train_labels.txt"
print("Loading the images...")
train_and_test_sets = load_images(dataset_path,test_labels_file,train_labels_file)
print("Images loaded sucessfully!")


#Now, I'm going to save some things in variables for a clearer code
train_image_batch = train_and_test_sets['train_image_batch']
train_label_batch = train_and_test_sets['train_label_batch']
test_image_batch = train_and_test_sets['test_image_batch']
test_label_batch = train_and_test_sets['test_label_batch']

"""THIS IS FOR SHOWING THE SETS, JUST FOR DEBBUGING
with tf.Session() as sess:

  # initialize the variables
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # initialize the queue threads to start to shovel data
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  print("from the train set:")

  for i in range(31):
    print(sess.run(train_image_batch))

  print("from the test set:")
  for i in range(11):
    print(sess.run(test_label_batch))

  # stop our queue threads and properly close the session
  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  sess.close()

"""

sess = tf.Session()


#Now, I'm going to save some things in variables for a clearer code
train_image_batch = train_and_test_sets['train_image_batch']
train_label_batch = train_and_test_sets['train_label_batch']
test_image_batch = train_and_test_sets['test_image_batch']
test_label_batch = train_and_test_sets['test_label_batch']



sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


#Firstly we get the prediction
prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)

#Cross Entropy is what we are going to try to reduce
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#----------PROBLEM HERE
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)


# Here it's where the train it's going to be made
train_images = sess.run(train_image_batch)
train_labels = sess.run(train_label_batch)
test_images = sess.run(test_image_batch)
test_labels = sess.run(test_label_batch)
with sess.as_default():
    index_for_batch = 1
    for i in range(50):
        print("generating batches")
        #batch_image = train_image_batch[index_for_batch].eval(session=sess)
        #batch_label = train_label_batch[index_for_batch].eval(session=sess)
        print("generated")
        if (i%5 == 0) and (i != 0):
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x:train_images, y: train_labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
            print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))

        print("*********Doing training step***********")
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: train_images, y: train_labels, keep_prob: 0.5})

        if(index_for_batch + 1 > len(train_image_batch)):
            index_for_batch = 1
        else:
            index_for_batch = index_for_batch + 1

#Here we are gong to test the accuracy of the training
print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: test_images, y: test_labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

**EDIT ERROR WITH OPS NAMES**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got -1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
         [[Node: Slice_1 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Shape_2, Slice_1/begin, Slice_1/size)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convolutional_net.py", line 295, in <module>
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: train_images, y: train_labels, keep_prob: 0.5})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1449, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3668, in _run_using_default_session
    session.run(operation, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got -1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
         [[Node: Slice_1 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Shape_2, Slice_1/begin, Slice_1/size)]]

Caused by op 'Slice_1', defined at:
  File "convolutional_net.py", line 264, in <module>
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1443, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels = _flatten_outer_dims(labels)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1245, in _flatten_outer_dims
    array_ops.shape(logits), [math_ops.sub(rank, 1)], [1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 484, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2868, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected begin[0] == 0 (got -1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
         [[Node: Slice_1 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Shape_2, Slice_1/begin, Slice_1/size)]]
```

Comment: It looks like you're having a problem with a slice node. Unfortunately, the error message indicates that it's using a tf-generated name, so it's a little hard to track down which is the problem. Could you name your ops (doc at: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#slice_input_producer)? i.e.: `tf.train.slice_input_producer(
                                    [test_images, test_labels],
                                    shuffle=False, name="test_images")`

Comment: @saeta sure, thank you. I've updated the post with the whole error with the ops name added

Comment: Looks like it's happening somewhere in the line: `cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))`. I don't have a more specific pointer based on just briefly looking at the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: @saeta thank you! I will look and try to figure out what's going on there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the code, the problem stems from the shape of the arguments to [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). According to the documentation:

> `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape `[batch_size, num_classes]` and the same dtype (either `float16`, `float32`, or `float64`).

Your code calls `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y)`, so let's look at the shapes of the arguments:

- `prediction` is the value returned from `convolutional_neural_network(x)`, and it has shape `[batch_size, N_CLASSES]`. (The placeholder for `x` represents `batch_size` as `None`, so that it can be dynamic.)
- `y` is defined as `y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)`. The placeholder has no shape information, so it is statically unknown (which partly explains the poor error message... see below for more about that). To find out the actual shape of `y`, we can look at how you feed the placeholder, and it appears that you feed it with a list of integers, parsed from the input file, where the integer represents the true label for the corresponding example.

To fix this problem, you should replace `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` with its **sparse** counterpart, [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), which can handle input data in the format that you are using:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
```

(An alternative approach would be to use [`tf.one_hot(y, N_CLASSES)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#one_hot) to convert `y` into the appropriate one-hot encoding for `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`, but that can be less efficient because it has to materialize a potentially large matrix for the target values.)

Note that the reason you are getting a runtime error for this problem is because of how the [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder) for `y` is defined, without a static shape. If you defined it as being a vector, you would get an error at graph construction time:

```
# `y` is a (variable-length) vector.
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! Now it works but it is giving me the following error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc` so I have to see where the memory goes. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Hi, I have another question if it's possible. I had to reduce the model complexity for computing reasons. Now, when I try to run the trainer, I get the following error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[80,2] labels_size=[5,2]
         [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_2, Reshape_3)]]`. If I try one of your answers to another question, using `tf.squeeze(y)` I get the error that tthe vector should be 1-D. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and wasting your time with this. I've searched a lot but I can't find an answer.